# Sci-fi movie with "good Samaritan" protagonist moving to a desert planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall seeing this scene on TV a while ago, but never managed to find the movie:

The protagonist is moving to a desert planet where water is extremely precious, however he is in a position of power and is given a house with luxuries such as plants.

As he enters the house, some servants give him a wet towel to freshen himself. When he is finished the servants try to gather the wasted water and sell it to some peasants just outside. Our protagonist (apparently a good Samaritan) says the water should not be sold but given for free.

I thought this could be a deleted scene from Dune, as it features the protagonist moving to a desert planet as part of the ruling family, but I did not find it in it (even looking in an extended version).

Judging from my memories of the image quality the movie was not very recent, probably from the 80s. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Servants selling water from wet towels, and being forbidden to (by Duke Leto) _is_ a thing in Dune.  Which version did you look at?

Comment: @DavidW - Did that scene appear in the movie, or just the mini-series?

Comment: It's definitely a scene in the book, so there's a reasonable chance it's come up in a screen adaptation, the trick is working out which one.

Comment: I fast forwarded through the Lynch movie. The only scene with towels I found was when Lady Jessica inspected her house staff, and that did not include any talk about selling them. So at least in the German theatrical release of the Lynch Dune movie (this was some pirated thing on YT) this does not come up.

Comment: In Dune 2000 there is a talk on a banquet about this "... my towel was taken away to save its water..."

Comment: And in Dune 2000 Jessica Atreides stops that tradition at the moment when maid was trying to sell water from the wet towel.

Comment: @Yaroslav Kornachevskyi   Exactly what I was about to post. She says water will never again be sold at the Atreides' door. https://youtu.be/mRlAKJfRtRc?t=1538

Comment: That was absolutely it! Thanks everyone, I had no idea adaptations of Dune other than the movie had been even made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer (Dune 2000) has been given in the comments.